# twig display images by number

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to display a star number based on my variable. Example I have in a first loop of elements and each element has a value that goes from 1 to 5. If an element has a value of 2 I would like to display 2 images.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your image location in Project?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your question :

```
{% set val = 1 %}
{% for i in 1..val %}
    <img src="{{ asset('image/star.png') }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Here `val` should be your element that can hold the dynamic value of 1 to 5. And make sure you have the image path correct in `asset`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you is exactly the subtlety that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Example will help you:

```
{% set n = 5 %}
{% for i in 1..n %}
    <img src="{{ asset('your-location/foo{{ 1 }}.jpg') }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done that, using a twig function. You pass a number to that function, and it renders a twig template with the desired number of stars.

Comment: In fact but it is for the sequel that I block

Comment: I use the for twig {% for i in 1..4 %} {% enfor %}